# How to reset notifyAuthFailure flag on Android device (android.accounts.AccountManager)

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, reset, flags

I am developping an Android app and I would like to reset the notifyAuthFailure flag on my device so that I am prompted again by my device.

I have the following method call:

accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/‌​analytics.readonly", ***true***, new AccountManagerCallback() {

[See api here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29)

How do I reset my Android device in order to be prompted again?

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution? I'm in the same situation :(